# /dev tmpfs question

Tags: filesystems, udev

I am confused where the **devtmpfs** filesystem is on my Linux system, I have read on it and I heard it is a virtual filesystem so it should be shown when I run the **df -a** command it should show the **devtmpfs** but it doesn't.

Since **devtmpfs** is a **virtual** **filesystem** I thought since it's **virtual** that's why it's not showing so I thought of searching for the /proc filesystem which is also virtual but **/proc** is showing. So my question is where is **devtmpfs**?

Here is my output of **df -a** :

```
root@buster10:/dev$ df -a
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
sysfs                  0        0         0    - /sys
proc                   0        0         0    - /proc
udev             1916492        0   1916492   0% /dev
devpts                 0        0         0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs             396232    11448    384784   3% /run
/dev/sda2      955878772 12422396 894830612   2% /
securityfs             0        0         0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs            1981144   123836   1857308   7% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1981144        0   1981144   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup2                0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/unified
cgroup                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
pstore                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/pstore
efivarfs               0        0         0    - /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
bpf                    0        0         0    - /sys/fs/bpf
cgroup                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
cgroup                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
cgroup                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma
cgroup                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
cgroup                 0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
systemd-1              -        -         -    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
mqueue                 0        0         0    - /dev/mqueue
debugfs                0        0         0    - /sys/kernel/debug
hugetlbfs              0        0         0    - /dev/hugepages
/dev/sda1         523248     5220    518028   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs             396228     5876    390352   2% /run/user/1000
fusectl                0        0         0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
gvfsd-fuse             0        0         0    - /run/user/1000/gvfs
binfmt_misc            0        0         0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
tracefs                -        -         -    - /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s mounted on `/dev`. To see the file system type, run `mount`; it should show something like

```
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=16392524k,nr_inodes=4098131,mode=755)
```

which confirms it’s a `devtmpfs`.

Comment: ah i see, thank you my friend for clearing this up for me! but why does it not come up on the df output?

Comment: `df` shows the mounted device, not the file system type. For virtual file systems the device is often set to match the type (`proc`, `cgroup` etc.) but it doesn’t have to be, and `/dev` ends up mounted in such a way as to show `udev` rather than `devtmpfs`.